# Continuity of a piecewise function problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Find all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $x$.

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
           \cosh x & x\leq 0 \\
           \frac{x}{e^x \sin x} & x\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{n\pi\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\} \\
           0 & x\in \{n\pi\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\} \}
        \end{cases}$$

I can show that $f$ is continuous for $x\leq 0$ but showing continuity for $x>0$ seems a bit more difficult and I would very much appreciate help since I don't know how to proceed with that case.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$ the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{n\pi\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ as composition of continuous functions.

For $x\in \{n\pi\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\} \}$ it's not contiuous due to $$\lim_{x\to n\pi} \left|\frac{x}{e^x \sin x}\right| = +\infty$$